# R sha1sum of file

Tags: r

I want to make a sha1 sum of a file using R.

My system is Windows 10 running RStudio 1.4.

This works:

```
md5sum <- md5sum(file)
```

This doesnt:

```
sha1sum <- sha1sum(file)
```

"Could not find function sha1sum"

Comment: There is a a `sha1` function in `digest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparison of `openssl::sha1` with `digest::sha1`:

```r
writeLines("foo", "quux.txt")
system2("sha1sum", c("quux.txt"), stdout = TRUE)
# [1] "855426068ee8939df6bce2c2c4b1e7346532a133 *quux.txt"
as.character(openssl::sha1(file("quux.txt")))
# [1] "855426068ee8939df6bce2c2c4b1e7346532a133"
digest::sha1("quux.txt")
# [1] "ad1a86aea4360a7d5c5fb0265f00438f6d7664a2"
```

That starts to show the problem, one disagrees with the others. One way to see what is going on is to change the contents of the file but keep the filename the same:

```r
writeLines("foofoofoo", "quux.txt")
as.character(openssl::sha1(file("quux.txt")))
# [1] "47673505b61b548b176d3d0449d7f6a4f3e9e09e"
system2("sha1sum", c("quux.txt"), stdout = TRUE)
# [1] "47673505b61b548b176d3d0449d7f6a4f3e9e09e *quux.txt"
digest::sha1("quux.txt")
# [1] "ad1a86aea4360a7d5c5fb0265f00438f6d7664a2"
```

The first two changed (this is expected) and remain the same, but the third from `digest::sha1` *has not changed* despite the contents having changed. While it is theoretically possible that two files with different contents can produce the same SHA1 checksum, this is not that case.

BTW: depending on your use, SHA1 is no longer recommended for secure hashing, preferring SHA256 or SHA512 or other stronger hash function.

Another BTW: don't forget the use of `file(.)` in `openssl::sha1`, otherwise you're doing exactly the same mistake.

```r
writeLines("foo", "quux.txt")
openssl::sha1("quux.txt")
# [1] "08a72b849478907ae9de2ff46ba53ce6aeeba360"
as.character(openssl::sha1(file("quux.txt")))
# [1] "855426068ee8939df6bce2c2c4b1e7346532a133"

writeLines("foofoofoo", "quux.txt")
openssl::sha1("quux.txt")
# [1] "08a72b849478907ae9de2ff46ba53ce6aeeba360"
### has not changed!

as.character(openssl::sha1(file("quux.txt")))
# [1] "47673505b61b548b176d3d0449d7f6a4f3e9e09e"
```

The help doc may not be perfectly clear on this. From `?openssl::sha1`:

```
       x: character vector, raw vector or connection object.
```

The fact that it operates on a string or a file is polymorphism ... and as convenient as that can be, it can also lead (often!) to misunderstandings of what is going on. If you think about it, how does the function know that what you're looking for is intended to be a file? If it checks with `file.exists` that it exists, then it will give you the checksum of the contents of the file; if not, the checksum of the string. If you run the code and expect it to check a file and the file doesn't exist, *I would expect an error*, but returning the checksum of the string that you thought was a file and the function thought was a string will ... break many assumptions in your use-case. (I would suggest that they use clear arguments such as `text=` and `file=` or `con=`.)

Comment: You can in fact get the reference output from `digest` too as that is how we validate the algorithmn but it required a combination of arguments I always forget -- you need to omit the serialization header for R and force ascii, if memory serves. It's all in the unit tests and possibly even in the help page...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, are you saying that there is a way to use `digest::sha1` on a file (without reading the file into R's environment)? I may be missing it in the docs. (I recognize it's your package.)

Comment: No, sorry, my bad. Maybe I misunderstand the question here.  What I was referring to is right at the top of the example section -- the 'magic' incantation is `serialize=FALSE`.  That doesn't away from the fact of the other confusion also pointed out that a filename is not the same as a filecontent...